# GCP Instance Template with Container undefined

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I have a nasty problem where any new instance templates I attempt to create will not register my Container Registry containers, no matter what I do.

My existing container images work, but any new attempts to push new containers (either to their own registry or even with a new tag in the one that works) shows up as undefined no matter what. Upon launching an instance with the template, the logs say "Unable to fetch container '' ".

The containers DO exist, and when I launch an instance directly with the containers in question, everything works perfectly. This is however not helpful as I rely heavily on autoscaling for my production use case, and cannot create any new instance groups since I cannot create the correct templates.

Comment: Please edit your question. There are no details for us to review.

Comment: I'm seeing this with the Cloud Console and with gcloud beta.  But gcloud "regular" seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create-with-container#--container-image) to create a Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance template that runs a container image:

For example:

```
$ gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container instance-template-1 --container-image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox
```

creates the instance-template-1 that runs the 'busybox' image.

The issue could be related to your image, as you can check your image: 
[Push and pull images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry) with Container Registry.

And [Managing images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing) hosted in Container Registry, for example listing image, tagging image, copying images to new registry